# Want to add comma between values then export to csv

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, export

I have a number of values in a csv file:

400105115

400114115

400503115

I want to put a comma after each value, so it would look like this:

400105115, 400114115, 400503115,

This is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy 
data=numpy.loadtxt(fname='/home/user/Desktop/caseno.csv', delimiter=',')
data2= [ int(x) for x in data ]
data3=list(data2)
print(data3)

import pandas
pd = pandas.DataFrame(data3)
pd.to_csv("mylist.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

This problem is that this leads to the following output:

400105115

400114115

400503115

It doesn't add any commas in, which I thought creating a list would do. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have only 1 field by line in your input. No separator can appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_fwf(file, sep=";",  header=None, widths=[1] * 9)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  4  0  0  1  0  5  1  1  5
1  4  0  0  1  1  4  1  1  5
2  4  0  0  5  0  3  1  1  5

df.to_csv("mylist.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly you want to add field delimiter for the output .csv file. As per the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Just use a sep flag.For example if you want to use a tab after each value :

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='/t', encoding='utf-8')
```

By default value for sep is ‘,’

Comment: I tried that is the following code, but it still doesn't insert a comma between the values in the output csv file.  df = pandas.DataFrame(data3)                          
df.to_csv("mylist.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input everyone. I was able to solve it with:
df.to_csv(..., line_terminator=',\n').